# Can I set the limits of NIntegrate symbolic in a multidimensional integral?

Tags: numerical-integration

I have written my integral as follows:

```
NIntegrate[ 
 f[re, rp, r], {re, 0, \[Infinity]}, {r, 
  0, \[Infinity]}, {rp, RealAbs[re - r], re + r}]
```

but it returns error due to limits of rp, How can I evaluate this integral numerically? I can evaluate integral over `rp` analytically using by `Integrate` command and then numerical integrate over `r` and `re`, But I want to check my integral numerically too, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

For example with Boole

```
NIntegrate[
 Boole[Abs[re - r] < rp < re + r] (rp^2 - re + Sqrt[r]), 
{re, 0, 10}, {r, 0, 11}, {rp, 0, 21}]
```

Comment: Thanks. can I change the limits of re and r to mine, namely o to infinite?

Comment: In my example not, because integral explodes, but if your integral is convergent, yes.

Comment: the limits of rp is just RealAbs[re - r] to re + r, How can apply your code? you specify a real number limits for rp at the end.

Answer (score 0):

No problem with this integrand:

```
NIntegrate[ 
 Exp[-re] Exp[-rp] r^2, {re, 0, \[Infinity]}, {r, 
  0, \[Infinity]}, {rp, RealAbs[re - r], re + r}]
(*  6.  *)
```

The problem is with your `f`?

Comment: Maybe! I get this warning: NIntegrate::nlim: rp = RealAbs[-r+re] is not a valid limit of integration.

Comment: @Wisdom Does my code work for you? I used V12.3.1 online (Linux). Just testing on my Mac, I get a convergence error, but not a syntax error.

Comment: Yes your code works for me, but for mine doesn't!

Comment: @Wisdom That seems odd.  There are characters that are invisible.  It's rare, but it has happened that someone managed to enter an invisible character; and that was the source of an error.  You could trying typing the input in a new cell. Or if you know how to read the cell expression, you could look at that (menu Cell > Show Expression).

Comment: Thanks bro! I will check it out